# jquery TimePicker plugin isn not using the default value

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using [Trent Richardson's Timepicker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I am running to issues with adding value attribute to the input field. If I set the value attribute on the input field, the timepicker is not displaying the value in the input field, but it reads the value for the timepicker. See the example code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kasulachetu/7fug98m3/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="21 Aug 2014 01:00" />
  <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="25 Aug 2014 01:00" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
var startDate = $("#start_date"),
endDate = $("#end_date");

$.timepicker.datetimeRange(
    startDate,
    endDate,
    {
      minInterval: (1000*60*60),
      dateFormat: 'dd M yy', 
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      start: {}, // start picker options
      end: {} // end picker options                 
    }
```

);

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be suitable for your needs, but if your requirements allow you to leave out the `.datetimeRange` property, as well as give your inputs class names, you can apply the `.datetimepicker` method to show the time portion of the inputs' value.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcbride2010/7fug98m3/76/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="21 Aug 2014 01:00" class="dateTimeInput" />
<input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="25 Aug 2014 01:00" class="dateTimeInput"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".dateTimeInput").datetimepicker(
    {
       minInterval: (1000*60*60),
       dateFormat: 'dd M yy', 
       timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
       start: {}, // start picker options
       end: {} // end picker options
    }
);
```

Comment: This is how I implemented before. I used the [example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#rest_examples) from Trent's site. But he has datetimeRange function in the API, where he explained it in his book. This is where I ran into issues. I will probably revert my changes to existing implementation.